# Subprocess call error in django application

Tags: django

I am trying to convert topojson file in django application using `subprocess.call()` function.
My Application running on UWSGI & NGINX

My Code:

```
geojsonfile_path="/home/testuser/jsonfile/geojson.json"
topojsonfile_path="/home/testuser/jsonfile/topojson.json"

command = ["topojson","-o",""+topojsonfile_path+"","--bbox","levels="+geojsonfile_path+""]
subprocess.call(command)
```

Getting Error:

```
internal/process/stdio.js:166
      throw new Error('Implement me. Unknown stream file type!');
      ^

Error: Implement me. Unknown stream file type!
    at createWritableStdioStream (internal/process/stdio.js:166:13)
    at process.getStdout [as stdout] (internal/process/stdio.js:10:14)
    at console.js:100:37
    at NativeModule.compile (bootstrap_node.js:493:7)
    at Function.NativeModule.require (bootstrap_node.js:434:18)
    at get (bootstrap_node.js:255:34)
    at Object.module.exports [as topology] (/usr/lib/node_modules/topojson/lib/topojson/topology.js:72:5)
    at output (/usr/lib/node_modules/topojson/bin/topojson:284:25)
    at notify (/usr/lib/node_modules/topojson/node_modules/queue-async/queue.js:47:18)
    at Object.await (/usr/lib/node_modules/topojson/node_modules/queue-async/queue.js:62:25)
```

I am running command line or separate python file it's working. But i am running inside Django application this conversion is not working. 
Please help me.

Comment: From your description and the stack trace it seems `topojson` needs stdout to work - try `subprocess.call(command, stdout=PIPE)`

Comment: It's not working i am getting same error.